# Ошибка MSB3027 не удалось скопировать "obj\...\Program.exe" в "bin\...\Program.exe". Превышено допустимое число повторных попыток (10)

Tags: c#

При попытке компиляции появляются две проблемы. В интернете не смог найти разъяснение. Сам понять пока не могу. Кто подскажет?

> Ошибка    MSB3027 не удалось скопировать
> "D:\C#\MathOperations\MathOperations\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MathOperations.exe"
> в "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MathOperations.exe". Превышено допустимое
> число повторных попыток (10). Произошел сбой. "MathOperations (7068)"
> блокирует этот файл
>
> Ошибка    MSB3021 не удалось скопировать файл
> "D:\C#\MathOperations\MathOperations\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MathOperations.exe"
> в "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MathOperations.exe". Процесс не может
> получить доступ к файлу "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MathOperations.exe",
> так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

[image]

Comment: Скорее всего этот файл запущен. Закройте его.

Comment: Вы работаете с потоками в коде своего приложения? Если да - покажите, как именно.

Answer (score 5):

У вас уже запущен экземпляр `MathOperations.exe`. Из-за этого MSBuild не может заменить старый экзешник новым сбилженным и после 10 неудачных попыток бросает это дело.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас есть незакрытые потоки.

Для того, что бы исправить это, откройте диспетчер задач и завершите процесс вашего приложения.

Для того, что бы такого больше не повторялось, в событие FormClosing введите это:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Данный кусок кода, завершает все процессы связанные с вашим приложением

Comment: Почему этот ответ неверный? Я сам сталкивался с такой же проблемой 2 недели назад. А что больше, помогло автору, будет решать он.

Comment: Лучше запускать фоновые потоки с флагом Background, или использовать пул

Comment: PashaPahsa, возможно он юзает System.Threard

Comment: Ок, первые 2 абзаца ответа - нормальные, а далее что? Вот это вот `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` - очень плохой костыль, который может привести к разного рода неприятным последствиям.

Comment: Этот код, ставится в событие: закрытие формы, он поможет в этой проблеме. А костыль это или нет, решать каждому

Comment: В нем нет необходимости, если вы будете запускать потоки с флагом [`myThread.IsBackground = true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netframework-4.8). Только и всего. А еще лучше вообще не юзать `Thread`, а использовать для параллельных операций `Task.Run(() => { ваш код; })` и забыть про существование `Thread` до тех пор, пока вы сознательно не поймете, что он вам реально нужен (99,99% - что это не случится никогда).

Comment: Я не знаю что юзает автор этой темы, поэтому дал "универсальный" код, который 100% поможет в этой ситуации

Comment: всем спасибо, через диспетчер задач закрыл MathOperations.exe, хотя почему он был открыт я не понял. а по поводу остальных System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();,  myThread.IsBackground = true, Task.Run(() => { ваш код; }) извините я не знаю что это такое пока и как этим пользоваться

Comment: Если мой совет вам помог, ставьте галочку, как помог в решение)

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer еще раз, ваш совет с Kill - вредный, это плохая практика. И если у вас есть реально работающие потоки, которые надо завершить, нужно делать нормальную синхронизацию, использовать `CancellationToken` и передавать его в код потока, чтобы код, когда токен сработает, мог нормально завершиться. И не в коем случае не делать то, что вы предлагаете. А в вышеупомянутом обработчике события просто вызывать `cts.Cancel()` для `CancellationTokenSource`. Штука очень полезная, если вы используете многопоточность, погуглите примеры, использовать это очень просто.

Comment: @aepot давайте ещё раз, почему это вредно? Если у человека 1000 потоков, то это максимально тупо, для каждого прописывать это

Comment: К примеру у меня есть поток, который к примеру отправляет данные на сервер по сети или пишет на диск, или в базу данных или в пользовательский файл. Юзер закрывает приложение, я убиваю поток, как вы сказали - данные потеряны. Вы в реальности можете делать как вам вздумается, без вопросов. Ваш код - ваши баги, но вместо того чтобы выдумывать отговорки, попробуйте реально вникнуть в то, о чем я вам писал. Это может оказаться полезным. У меня есть несколько очень больших проектов, и там очень много потоков, и я не использую то, что вы предлагаете, и все нормально работает, ничего не виснет.

Comment: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Introduction) - там есть ссылка на русский перевод, если по-английски тяжело читать.

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer вариант с `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` - это лечение симптомов. Если где-то не-фоновый поток утек - то нужно искать где именно. Потому что наличие таких потоков - это потенциальные проблемы. Возможно, где-то результат обработки не отобразился (раз поток потеряли), может быть где-то файл недописанный останется. Т.е. да, замеченные симптомы пройдут (отрубание головы тоже помогает от насморка), но где-то в другом месте вылезет.

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer по поводу 1000 потоков - этот флаг прописан по умолчанию на потоках из пулла. Если у человека 1000 потоков не из пулла, с ручным управлением - то скорее всего результат работы подвисших потоков не учтен. И рубануть их - это верный способ проигнорировать проблему в логике.